# How can I pass input from request validation file to previous view in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I made a request file in Laravel and put my validations on it
but when the request redirects to the previous view, I want to pass input with redirection.

This is my request file code:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdatePasswordRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'password' => 'required',
            'newPassword' => [
                'required', 'string', 'min:10', 'regex:/[a-z]/', 'regex:/[A-Z]/', 'regex:/[0-9]/', 'regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/',
            ],
            'confirmPassword' => 'required',
        ];
    }
    
    public function messages(): array
    {
        return [
            'password.same' => 'password doesn\'t match with the current password',
            'newPassword.min' => 'new password must be at least 10 digits',
            'newPassword.regex' => "<ul><li>must contain at least one lowercase letter</li>
                                    <li>must contain at least one uppercase letter</li>
                                    <li>must contain at least one digit</li>
                                    <li>must contain a special character for example [* # & %]</li></ul>",
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to pass this input ['tab' => 'updatePassword']

I tried to but this function:

```
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput(['tab' => 'updatePassword'])->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
```

And I will use `old('tab')` in view, but it doesn't work.

Comment: that doesn't sound like an input, that just sounds like you want to flash a session variable

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the `failedValidation()` method of the `FormRequest` class.

```
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        redirect()->back()
            ->withInput(['tab' => 'updatePassword'])
            ->withErrors($validator)
    );
}
```

---

```
<input type="hidden" name="tab" value="{{ old('tab') }}">
```